# WordPress navigation menu is not loading

Tags: wordpress

I am working on my custom theme in wordpress, I have a problem in the navigation in my site, when I open the site, the main navigation is not loading.
Below are the codes.
Any assistance is highly appreciated. 
Thanks.

***Function.php*** file

```
function register_my_menus() {
    register_nav_menus( array(
            'menu-1' => esc_html__( 'Primary', 'nethub' ),
    ) );
}
    add_action( 'init', 'register_my_menus' );
```

Then in **header.php** the code is

```
       <?php
        wp_nav_menu(
            array(
                'theme_location' => 'menu-1',
                'menu' => 'primary-menu',
                'container' => false,
                'items_wrap' => '<ul class="rd-navbar-nav">%3$s</ul>',
                )
        );                               
    ?>
    </div>
```

Comment: Also just making sure that its `functions.php` and not `function.php`.

Answer (score 0):

Have you created a menu in the menus edit screen and set it to the "Primary" location?  Also think you can remove the `'menu' => 'primary-menu',` from your header.php:

```
// header.php
    <?php
        wp_nav_menu(array(
            'theme_location' => 'menu-1',
            'container' => false,
            'items_wrap' => '<ul class="rd-navbar-nav">%3$s</ul>',
        ));                              
    ?>
</div>
```